# Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot; missing Terminal, blank desktop after login

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, dell

I have performed dual boot on my [Dell Inspiron 7567](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-15-7567-laptop_service-manual_en-us.pdf) multiple times. Windows 10 was preinstalled; I set up dual boot of ubuntu 16.04 on its 1 TB HDD with 250 GB for Ubuntu.

It is not responding well after many attempts and become stuck after entering password and desktop becomes blank. There is no appearances of terminal also.

Comment: 1) For Terminal in Ubuntu, do `Ctrl-Alt-T`. 2) Is the HDD using an MBR partition table or GPT? Let's find out. From a Windows terminal window, do `diskpart` then `list disk`. Please copy the result, then do `exit` and come back here; click [edit] then paste the result of `list disk` into your original question. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please include some the steps you did in the Ubuntu installation. And also include other info such as Windows booting (BIOS or EFI), HDD (Raid/AHCI), etc.